# Inexpensive motor controller board with ROS driver

Tags: ros, driver, motor-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for an inexpensive DC brushed motor controller board with serial interface (preferably USB), encoder feedback, at least 12V/3A continuous current and ROS driver. The only direct reference I found is *ROS Motor Controller Drivers* at ROS Wiki, but it lists only 3 options and Roboteq AX2550 sort of qualifies, except of the cost. Are there any other options?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109241/inexpensive-motor-controller-board-with-ros-driver/) by [Paul Jurczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/9766/paul-jurczak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-12-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-11**:
My advise would be to widen your options and drop the ROS support requirement. Developing a ROS driver for a serial interface for a motor controller board should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What voltage?

I think that your best option is to get yourself and Arduino and some sort of motor control shield. It is trivial to write a program for it take commands and publish sensor data via the serial port.

You would then have to write a small ROS node that sends commands to the  arduino and publishes the encoder data back to ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-12-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul Jurczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/9766/paul-jurczak/) on 2013-12-11**:
12V or more. I'm considering using microcontroller board with motor driver and writing my own ROS driver - just wanted to know what are the options.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-12-11**:
I agree with Dereck and I am using that for two 12V motors at 6 A max.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2014-01-21**:
If you use an Arduino, then you can make use of rosserial (http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial), which already provides everything you need to publish and receive ROS messages.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Roboclaw has a lot of features and good reviews.  I hear you should buy directly from the manufacturer since earlier firmwares are buggy.

I would suggest just buying one of these and writing a rospy pyserial node to communicate to the controller:

http://www.orionrobotics.com/Motor-Controllers_c_125.html

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-12-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonyccd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25477/sonyccd/) on 2016-03-21**:
I have written a driver for this board

[link text](https://github.com/sonyccd/roboclaw_ros)